# How to add past 14 days items in a list view in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

There is one radio button column as open and closed, for open I want a view where only from created till 14 days should be shown and for closed the items closed within 14 days should be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your filter to show all items that created within the past 14 days

```
[Today]-14
```

[image]

Then add another filter for `closed` status

Comment: for closes it should be less than equal to right? and [Today]+14

Comment: @RonitGhosh you said the past 14 days not the coming so it should be [Today]-14 anyway ' less than equal' and [Today]+14 is the same  'greater than equal to'  [Today]-14, please if it helped you to solve your issue Mark it as answer with true sign beside my answer , thanks

Comment: You are welcome Please set it as answer if it helped you :)